# React Native PanResponder used with element has borderRadius

Tags: javascript, react-native, gesture, touches

I bind the PanResponder to an element which has the borderRadius style. Then when i click somewhere not on the circle but on the original area, it also triggered the event.

(just like the image show below, when click the area in the black rect outside the red circle, it also trigger the event bind to the red circle)

If someone know how to prevent this?

```
class touch extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        bg: 'red'
    }
   }
componentWillMount(){
    this.gestureHandlers = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder:    this._handleStartShouldSetPanResponder.bind(this),
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: this._handleMoveShouldSetPanResponder.bind(this),
    onPanResponderGrant: this._handlePanResponderGrant.bind(this),
    onPanResponderMove: this._handlePanResponderMove.bind(this),
    onPanResponderRelease: this._handlePanResponderEnd.bind(this),
    onPanResponderTerminate: this._handlePanResponderEnd.bind(this),
})
}

_handleStartShouldSetPanResponder(e, gestureState){
 return true;
}

_handleMoveShouldSetPanResponder(e, gestureState){
 return true;
}

_handlePanResponderGrant(e, gestureState){
 this.setState({bg: 'orange'});
}

_handlePanResponderEnd(e, gestureState){
 this.setState({bg: 'red'});
}
render() {

return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
 <View style={styles.test}>
   <View 
    {...this.gestureHandlers.panHandlers}
    style={[styles.rectBig, {
      "backgroundColor": this.state.bg
    }]}>
    </View>
    </View> 
</View>
 );}}
```

[example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YeSD.png)